# How can I touch and drag an animated image? here's my animation code:

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, drag-and-drop

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:50];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

    CGPoint abc =chem1.center;

    abc.y= 480;
    chem1.center=abc; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:50];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

    CGPoint def =chem2.center;

    def.y= 480 ;
    chem2.center=def; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:50];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

    CGPoint hij =nat1.center;

    hij.y= 480;
    nat1.center=hij; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:50];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

    CGPoint klm =nat2.center;

    klm.y= 480;
    nat2.center=klm;  
}
```

I'd really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question: **how to tap an animated image** and **how to drag an image**.

---

## How to tap an animated image.

### Background

When you are animating a view (or more accurately its layer) the property that you change (in your case the `position` (by setting `center`)) is changed to its final value right away. If you only animate (like with a CABasicAnimation, then the properly might not change at all.

This means that if you try to tap the view (or layer) it will be at the position that you moved it to (its final position (despite any duration or repeat count of the animation).

### Hit test a moving layer

To be able to hit test something that is moving you need to hit test against the [`presentationLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) of the layer of the view that you are trying to tap.

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:[self view]];

if ([[[[self movingView] layer] presentationLayer] hitTest:touchPoint]) {
    // Yeah, you hit the moving (animating) layer!
}
```

Now that the user has tapped a moving view (image in your case) you can begin to handle the drag.

## How to drag an image

When you are dragging an image you move the layer to wherever the users finger is dragging the image.

### Remove to animation that moves the view

First you should cancel the ongoing animation for that view (having a name for the animation enables you to cancel only one animation.

```
[[[self movingView] layer] removeAllAnimations];
```

Or if you have set a name to the movement animation.

```
[[[self movingView] layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"nameOfMovingAnimation"];
```

### Move the view to the location of the users finger

Next you should (continuously) update the position of the view as the user moves its finger. You should not animate this since it will increase the time between the movement of the finger and the view and will make it seem like your application is lagging. *Animating while dragging does **not** make it look smooth.*

**Note:** since your question doesn't say what you want to do once the user are dragging the images or what happens when they drop them. I can't go much further in the explanation.

### Need more help?

Search the web (or StackOverflow) for something like: "iOS drag view" and you will probably find more information about how to drag your imageViews.

Otherwise ask another question on StackOverflow once you have gotten this far (i.e. you can tap on the moving images and they stop moving).

Comment: So it's not possible to enable the user interaction on animated images?

Comment: Yes it is. You just have to hit test the presentation layer to know when the user is taping an image and then use your standard code to drag it

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation. Does that help you understand how to implement this?